# Git hub plugin in jdeveloper 12c

Tags: git, github, jdeveloper

I need to push my code from jdeveloper to GitHub.

Can anyone help me with the steps to check in code from jdeveloper using GitHub plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JDeveloper has Git under the "Team" menu - see for example :
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/using-the-oracle-developer-cloud-service-for-git-version-management-for-jdeveloperadf-apps